# Stepper motor micros (millis) non-blocking delay simple example?

Tags: millis, stepper-motor

I am trying to get a simple non-blocking replacement for:

```
digitalWrite(stepPinX, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(500);
digitalWrite(stepPinX, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(500);
```

This is what I tried, and the stepper motor stays still:

```
const int dirPinX = 0;
const int stepPinX = 2;

unsigned long startMicros = micros();
unsigned long currentMicros;
const unsigned long period = 500;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(stepPinX, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPinX, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(dirPinX, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
  stepX();
}

void stepX()
{
  currentMicros = micros();  //get the current "time" (time since program start)

  if (currentMicros - startMicros >= period)  //test whether period elapsed
  {
    digitalWrite(stepPinX, HIGH);
  }
  if ((currentMicros - startMicros >= period) && (currentMicros - startMicros <= period*2))
  {
    digitalWrite(stepPinX, LOW);
  } 

  startMicros = currentMicros;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to correct this? (I do not want to use a library like Accelstepper. I want to use millis/micros.)

Comment: the second `if` statement will execute only very infrequently ... why have a separate `if` statement for the two output states?

Comment: edited question and program

Comment: do only one `if (currentMicros - startMicros >= period)` ... keep track of `stepPinX` state

Answer (score 1):

Your `stepX()` function looks like this:

```cpp
void stepX()
{
  currentMicros = micros();
  // conditionally do some stuff..
  startMicros = currentMicros;
}
```

Since there is nothing that can block it, it will always execute very
fast. This means that, by the time the function returns, `startMicros`
will be very close to the current time. Then, on the following call,
`currentMicros - startMicros` will be very small, way smaller than
`period`, and the conditional code will never execute.

The solution is to change the meaning of `startMicros`: instead of
representing the time of the last call to `stepX()`, let it represent
the time when the last step started. For this, you have to reset it only
when finishing a step:

```cpp
void stepX()
{
  currentMicros = micros();
  if (currentMicros - startMicros < period) {           // 1st phase
    digitalWrite(stepPinX, HIGH);
  } else if (currentMicros - startMicros < 2*period) {  // 2nd phase
    digitalWrite(stepPinX, LOW);
  } else {                                              // complete cycle
    startMicros = currentMicros;        
  }
}
```

Comment: ```if ((currentMicros - startMicros >= period) && (currentMicros - startMicros <= period*2))
  {
    digitalWrite(stepPinX, LOW);
    startMicros = currentMicros;
  }```

Like that? Same result as before.

Comment: @adamaero: Oops! Indeed, I did not notice that the logic of the `if` conditions was wrong. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `startMicros` and `currentMicros` values always stay close to each other because of using `micros()` before and after the conditional block. Since the conditional block executes faster than 500 micros, resulting in never entering the conditional block.

From here you can take two approaches,

- **Approach 01:** Play with your code variables and debug in realtime to see what's wrong and where. Then tweak,debug, repeat until you reach the desired result
- **Approach 02:** Rethink w.r.t the code execution and simplify your code right from entry to exit in sequential steps.

Since your action can be simplified to a toggle operation every `500 microseconds`, we can refactor code similar to what I have written,

```
bool toggle_flag = false;
unsigned long last_toggle;
const unsigned long period = 500;
  
void setup() {
    last_toggle = micros();
    pinMode(stepPinX, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // Check to see if time elapsed
  if (micros() - last_toggle >= period ) {
      
      // Step 01: reset the last_toggle with current time
      last_toggle = micros();

      // Step 02: check toggle flag and perform the toggle action
      (toggle_flag) ? digitalWrite(stepPinX, HIGH) : digitalWrite(stepPinX, LOW);

      // Step 03: toggle the toggle flag variable after our action
      toggle_flag = !toggle_flag;

  }

}
```

Hope this answer helps.